# Installing ffmpeg with vcpkg

Tags: linux, visual-studio, ffmpeg, cmake, vcpkg

I've installed `ffmpeg` using `vcpkg install ffmpeg`

When I include the dependency in my cmake project, like so:

```
find_path(AVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIR libavcodec/avcodec.h)
find_library(AVCODEC_LIBRARY avcodec)
find_path(AVFORMAT_INCLUDE_DIR libavformat/avformat.h)
find_library(AVFORMAT_LIBRARY avformat)
find_path(AVUTIL_INCLUDE_DIR libavutil/avutil.h)
find_library(AVUTIL_LIBRARY avutil)
find_path(AVDEVICE_INCLUDE_DIR libavdevice/avdevice.h)
find_library(AVDEVICE_LIBRARY avdevice)

target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE
        ${AVCODEC_LIBRARY} ${AVFORMAT_LIBRARY} ${AVUTIL_LIBRARY} ${AVDEVICE_LIBRARY}
    )
```

My windows build works fine, however, on linux, I get the error:

```
[29/29] Linking CXX shared library libjni.so
2021-11-14T12:38:02.510164800Z FAILED: libjni.so 
2021-11-14T12:38:02.510171600Z : && /usr/bin/g++-11 -fPIC -O3 -DNDEBUG   -shared -Wl,-soname,libjni.so -o libjni.so CMakeFiles/jni.dir/src/jni.cpp.o CMakeFiles/jni.dir/src/core/audio.cpp.o CMakeFiles/jni.dir/src/core/files.cpp.o CMakeFiles/jni.dir/src/core/fs/file_utils.cpp.o CMakeFiles/jni.dir/src/core/spectrogram.cpp.o CMakeFiles/jni.dir/src/core/utils.cpp.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10 -Wl,-rpath,/root/build/Release/_deps/fmt-build  /root/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib/libfftw3f.a  _deps/fmt-build/libfmt.so.8.0.1  _deps/xxhash-build/libxxhash.a  /root/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib/libavcodec.a  /root/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib/libavformat.a  /root/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib/libavutil.a  /root/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib/libavdevice.a  _deps/kistream_proto_cpp-build/libgenerated_srcs.a  -lm  -Wl,--as-needed  /root/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib/libprotobuf.a  -lpthread && :
2021-11-14T12:38:02.510185200Z /usr/bin/ld: /root/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib/libavcodec.a(h264_intrapred_10bit.o): warning: relocation against `ff_pw_512' in read-only section `.text'
2021-11-14T12:38:02.510187600Z /usr/bin/ld: /root/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib/libavcodec.a(vc1dsp_mmx.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `ff_pw_9' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, your issue is related to Position Independent Code. It can be resolved if you compile by giving -fPIC option in vcpkg.

You can look at [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/3577) github issue of vcpkg repo. They gave an example that how can add compiler option to vcpkg`s port CMake file.